# Astar Path going through walls when it shouldnt

Tags: numpy, path, a-star, numpy-ndarray

Im pulling in a chart with 0s and 1s, & 2 as my starting point, -1 as my ending point. my 1s are my walls. 
The Astar pathfinding should avoid the walls but it goes through them, does anyone know why?

```
grid = pd.read_csv(r'C:\Users\605760\Desktop\path rec\pat.csv',header=None)

# start point and goal

start, = zip(*np.where(grid==2))
goal, = zip(*np.where(grid==-1))


heuristic function for path scoring
##############################################################################
def heuristic(a, b):
    return np.sqrt((b[0] - a[0]) ** 2 + (b[1] - a[1]) ** 2)
def heuristic(a, b):
    return np.sqrt((b[0] - a[0]) ** 2 + (b[1] - a[1]) ** 2)
##############################################################################
# path finding function
##############################################################################
def astar(array, start, goal):
    neighbors = [(0,1),(0,-1),(1,0),(-1,0),(1,1),(1,-1),(-1,1),(-1,-1)]
    close_set = set()
    came_from = {}
    gscore = {start:0}
    fscore = {start:heuristic(start, goal)}
    oheap = []
    heapq.heappush(oheap, (fscore[start], start))

    while oheap:
        current = heapq.heappop(oheap)[1]
        if current == goal:
            data = []
            while current in came_from:
                data.append(current)
                current = came_from[current]
            return data
        close_set.add(current)
        for i, j in neighbors:
            neighbor = current[0] + i, current[1] + j
            tentative_g_score = gscore[current] + heuristic(current, neighbor)
            if 0 <= neighbor[0] < array.shape[0]:
                if 0 <= neighbor[1] < array.shape[1]:               
                    if array[neighbor[0]][neighbor[1]] == 1:
                        continue
                else:
                    # array bound y walls
                    continue
            else:
                # array bound x walls
                continue

            if neighbor in close_set and tentative_g_score >= gscore.get(neighbor, 0):
                continue

            if  tentative_g_score < gscore.get(neighbor, 0) or neighbor not in [i[1]for i in oheap]:
                came_from[neighbor] = current
                gscore[neighbor] = tentative_g_score
                fscore[neighbor] = tentative_g_score + heuristic(neighbor, goal)
                heapq.heappush(oheap, (fscore[neighbor], neighbor))

    return False
route = astar(grid, start, goal)
route = route + [start]
route = route[::-1]
print(route)

##############################################################################
# plot the path
##############################################################################
#extract x and y coordinates from route list
x_coords = []
y_coords = []


for i in (range(0,len(route))):
    x = route[i][0]
    y = route[i][1]
    x_coords.append(x)
    y_coords.append(y)
```

link to photo of what is showing 
https://drive.google.com/file/d/18dm1c86Uk4vv5rvmC-ZNOEbAkVCAKImr/view?usp=sharing